# How to pass login username and password to webpage asking for SSO details in powershell

Tags: powershell

[Getting login popup as in screenshot, even passing credential in script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40SBy.jpg)I wrote below code, to open servicenow portal with ticket number and passing credential but credentials are not passed and servicenow keep asking for username and password(SSO account).

My code flow:

1. opens servicenow URL containing ticket number
2. credentials passed using get-Credential to open webpage

Issue: username and password passed using Get-Credential are not accepted by servicenow URL and keep prompting for SSO login details. please let me know how to pass username and password.

`$targetUrl ="https://servicemanagement.contoso.net/textsearch.do?sysparm_ck=dummy&sysparm_tsgroups=&sysparm_view=text_search&sysparm_search=INC00011064" $Creds = Get-Credential -Message "Enter SSO credentials"  $page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Credential $Creds`

Below is the info from inspecting the elements.. I want to enter username and password and then to click on submit button. I'm completely new to PowerShell unfortunately so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<td class="Subheader" nowrap="" align="left" width="92">
<p align="right">Username: </p></td>
<td class="RowShadeHigh" nowrap="" width="250"><b>
<input name="USER" size="34" class="textinput" stype="float: left"> &nbsp;
</b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="Subheader" nowrap="" align="left" valign="center" width="92">
<p align="right">PassWord: </p></td>

<td class="Subheader" nowrap="" height="28">
<input name="Password" size="34" class="textinput" name="PASSWORD" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="if (event.keycode==13) submitForm();"> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Probably you need to prefix the domain information for your user account: `Consoto\Username` or just `.\Username`

Comment: I tried with domain\username but still same issue, credentials are not passing and prompting to enter credentials manually. please suggest on how credentials can be passed via script.

Comment: Account disabled because you had too many attempts? Also check the concerned items in the creditial manager.

Comment: no, My account is working fine. Issue is when trying to open Serv icenow URL from script , the webpage loads and prompting to enter SSO username password inside webpage , whereas when opening same URL directly in browser webpage opens successfully without asking credentials.

Comment: could anyone help me on this please, i raised query on 1st Dec